# delete current object in underscore.js each() or other

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Delete current object in underscore.js each() or other ?

```js
_.each(fools, function(user) {
    if (user['great'] === true) {  
        // delete user from fools object ?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `filter` http://underscorejs.org/#filter

```
fools = _.filter(fools, function(user) {
    return !user['great'];
});
```

Or `reject`, which is just sugar.

Answer (score 3):

in each()

```js
_.each(fools, function(user, key) {
    if (user['great'] === true) {  
        delete fools[key];
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it leaves the value as undefined within the array, so the length of the array would not change.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [`_.reject`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject)?

From the underscore documentation:

> Returns the values in list without the elements that the truth test (iterator) passes. The opposite of filter.
>
> ```
> var odds = _.reject([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
> => [1, 3, 5]
> ```